# Sending data whose last character is dynamic in JDBC Request - JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I have a question in Jmeter!

I have a script in a JDBC request (INSERT).

One of the data must be dynamic. Each time I call, the last character of the data must be sequential (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...). Example "XXXHDLALA01", "XXXHDLALA02", "XXXHDLALA03", etc.

The data would be the same every time I insert, but I would only change the last characters, because they are sequential numbers.
The data is as follows:

ACTC104_04358798_20220202_00001

I need to change only the last one (ACTC104_04358798_20220202_00001, ACTC104_04358798_20220202_00002, ACTC104_04358798_20220202_00003, ACTC104_04358798_20220202_00004...)

Can I do this using some kind of regex?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element

1. If you add Counter and configure it as:

   [image]
2. In the JDBC Test Element use `${counter}` as the postfix for the dynamic part:

   ```
   ACTC104_04358798_20220202_${counter}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

You may also want to use [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) as well because `20220202` looks like current date to me

```
ACTC104_04358798_${__time(yyyyMMdd,)}_${counter}
```

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)